# Qual a diferença entre montador e compilador?

Tags: assembly, compiladores

Bom o que eu queria saber é qual a diferença entre compilador e montador? Já que ambos geram um arquivo binário e traduzem uma linguagem legível por humanos para binário.

Também poderia me mostrar qual o processo de montagem de um compilador?

Comment: Espero que a pergunta  não tenha ficado ruin

Comment: Mas esta pergunta não é semelhante só quero saber a diferença entre compilador e montador

Comment: As duas perguntas marcadas mostram as diferenças

Comment: Ok tudo bem ok :D