# O que é código objeto?

Tags: c, terminologia, compilação, assembly

O que é código objeto? Para que serve o código objeto? Como se chama o processo de tradução do código objeto para código de máquina?

Já vi falar até que a linguagem **C** usa **Assembly** como código objeto, isso esta certo? Então neste caso podemos chamar isso de processo de compilação ou montagem?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

O objeto é um binário gerado pelo compilador depois que já processou o código fonte. Ele costuma ficar em um arquivo para depois poder gerar o executável através do processo de [*linkedição*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101).

O código objeto é um código de máquina. O compilador gerou esse código de máquina.

C não usa Assembly como código objeto. Algum compilador específico de C pode gerar um código Assembly como linguagem intermediária para que depois o código objeto seja gerado por um montador. É um detalhe de implementação de um compilador.

Já vi alguém usando o termo para o arquivo de linguagem intermediária antes da geração do código de máquina, mas não sei se isso está certo, me parece errado. Essa linguagem intermediária poderia ser o Assembly, mas se gera um fonte acho estranho ser o objeto. Nesse caso o Assembly seria o alvo (*target*) do compilador C e o Assembly então é o fonte (*source*) do montador. Então o código objeto seria o *target*.

Pra mim código objeto é quase sinônimo de código de máquina encapsulado de forma pronta para execução depois de colocada junto com outras partes em um executável.

Em alguns casos o código objeto pode ser agrupado em um arquivo de [biblioteca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119354/101). Você ainda não tem um executável, mas não tem os fontes.

[Para entender melhor sobre montador e compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/454207/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero estava com saudades das suas repostas obrigado

Comment: Kk se alguém tiver outra reposta envie por favor