# Qual a diferença entre código objeto e código intermediário?

Tags: c, terminologia, compiladores

[Nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454415/o-que-%C3%A9-codigo-objeto) um usuário respondeu que o código objeto é diferente de código intermediário.

Como a maioria de cursos dizem que o código objeto está no meio do processo, então não poderíamos chamá-lo de código intermediário? Então qual a diferença?

[image: como pode ver aqui:]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

O código intermediário pode ter várias formas, inclusive pode ser um fonte, enquanto que código objeto costuma ser um código de máquina. Não é que o objeto não possa ser um fonte, mas não costuma ser.

O código intermediário é uma forma mais fácil do compilador trabalhar. O código fonte segue as regras da linguagem, o que pode não ser fácil para o compilador lidar, então ele compila o fonte da linguagem para uma linguagem dele, que é intermediária porque não é o código final que é o código de máquina. A maioria dos compiladores complexos, que pretendem fazer otimização ou criar certas *features* tem isso, caso contrário o resultado será inferior ou será muito difícil trabalhar com isso internamente.

O assunto é um pouco complicado porque depende um pouco do contexto.

## Compilação em duas fases

Por exemplo, o código intermediário que o compilador de C# gera é o [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101) ([mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101)) e acaba ficando em um formato binário e é mandado como parte do executável. De certa forma aquilo é um código intermediário e está em um código que é um pouco um objeto, mas está encapsulado em um executável. Por isso é difícil definir bem essas coisas. O que é certo é que esse CIL não é o código de máquina executável, isso só ocorrerá depois que tenha um [JITting](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) (na maioria das implementações do CLR).

Algo parecido ocorre com outras linguagens [como Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101) e outras de *script* que o pessoal fala que é [interpretada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101), mas ela foi compilada antes. Em geral todas essas linguagens geram um código intermediário chamado *bytecode* (não achei *link daqui* para postar #ficaadica). Esse *bytecode*, não é o fonte da linguagem e não é o código de máquina. Em geral ele não é um texto, é um binário, é uma forma de Assembly que é gravado como código de máquina em uma plataforma virtual, ao contrário do código de máquina real que é para um processador que vai executar de verdade.

Alguns desses *bytecodes* serão JITtados e outros serão "interpretados". Não vou entrar em detalhes aqui.

## Uso interno de compiladores

Mas é muito comum que os compiladores usem um código intermediário que nem é exposto fora dele, é só para uso dele, então ele nem costuma (as vezes pode) gravá-lo em algum lugar.

Por exemplo [Rust diz que melhorou a velocidade do compilador quando passou adotar um código intermediário](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2016/04/19/MIR.html) em vez de fazer tudo no código original. Não sei se é verdade, ainda é muito lento. Ela tem dois código intermediários porque o *backend* é o LLVM.

Isso pode ser mais útil porque você separa o compilador em duas partes. Um *frontend* que pega o fonte do programa a ser compilado e cria um código intermediário. E um *backend* que pega esse código intermediário e gera o código de máquina para a plataforma alvo. Sem isso ele teria que fazer tudo junto e fica complicado.

Tem softwares que são só *backends* então a única forma de usá-los é através de um IR, como é o [caso do LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html).

O GCC tem alguns IRs próprios e pode gerar de terceiros como do LLVM.

O [IR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation) é a representação intermediária de um código, que é um termo genérico para falar sobre o que será o código intermediário.

## Conclusão

Eu não acho que o código objeto seja intermediário, são contextos diferentes, e o código objeto sendo o código de máquina definitivamente ele não é intermediário.

Não pode confundir o termo código nesses dois casos. O código intermediário é uma linguagem, o código objeto é um produto final. Mas de fato é o tipo de coisa que dá margem para interpretação. São funções diferentes.

A maioria dessas coisas só são úteis para quem está mexendo com compiladores e ferramentas ligadas ou faz coisas bem mais avançadas. Eu acho que todo mundo deveria aprender essas coisas para ser melhor, mas não fundamental. Um piloto não precisa entender de mecânica, mas ele será melhor se entender.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Tudo bem então quer dizer que codico objeto não é um codico intermediario?

Comment: De forma geral não. Inclusive no diagrama colocado depois na pergunta, naquele contexto fica claro que não é.

Comment: Sim obrigado pelas belas explicações

Comment: @Kate veja no [tour] a melhor forma de dizer obrigado.

Comment: Ok tudo bem ok :D